# How to run two sudo commands subsequently in python paramiko -SSH client linux?

Tags: python, paramiko

I am trying to do a ssh to my local machine - 127.0.0.1, which works fine.
Next, I am trying to run two commands through ssh client. However, I see that the next command fails. I could see that my tap device is created. However, the tap device is not turned up. Here is my code. I tried the ifconfig and it works fine.
However, it is the sudo commands that is creating a problem.

self.serverName is 127.0.0.1

```
  def configure_tap_iface(self):
        ssh = paramiko.SSHClient()
        print('SSH on to PC')
        ssh.set_missing_host_key_policy(paramiko.AutoAddPolicy())
        ssh.connect(self.serverName, username='zebra', password='Zebra@2018')
        stdin, stdout, stderr = ssh.exec_command('ifconfig')
        #print(stdout.read())
        session = ssh.get_transport().open_session()
        session.get_pty()
        session.exec_command('sudo ip address add 192.168.0.1/24 dev cloud_tap && sudo ip link set cloud_tap up')
        session.close()
        time.sleep(3)
        ssh.close()
```

Comment: If you do the same with some simple commands (not `sudo`), does it work?

Comment: yes, the simple command works without sudo

Comment: Is your account configured to run `sudo` passwordless? Can you run `sudo -l` from Paramiko, what does it display?

Comment: env_reset, mail_badpass, secure_path=/usr/local/sbin\\:/usr/local/bin\\:/usr/sbin\\:/usr/bin\\:/sbin\\:/bin\\:/snap/bin\n\nUser bali may run the following commands on pc-ubu:\n    (root) NOPASSWD: /sbin/ip\n    (ALL : ALL) ALL\n'

Answer (score 1):

You can use `sudo sh -c 'commands'` to run multiple shell commands in a single `sudo` invocation.

```
session.exec_command("sudo sh -c 'ip address add 192.168.0.1/24 dev cloud_tap && ip link set cloud_tap up'")
```

Comment: what does sh -c means? is sh for shell ? how about -c switch?

Comment: `sh -c 'commands; more commands'` says to read the script from the command line instead of from a script file.  Yes, `sh` is the standard Bourne shell which is generally used for noninteractive scripts even if you have a different interactive shell.